# Print PDF.JS without print btn

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I can see a pdf.js document in a digital viewer. Is it possible to print it without seeing a print button or the hotkey?

If I print with the browser function of printing, its just that one page, that I see.

I need it without the whole border stuff, just like the pdf and every page, not just what I see.

If I could have access to the original pdf somehow, this would be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Extension in FFox enabled right click again and then I could print the iframe to pdf